# Adding of two different buttons in two prototype cells of UITableView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am newbie in swift. I am trying to add two different buttons in two prototype cells of UITableViewController. These buttons will lead to different actions. I have done it in the following way but haven't succeeded could anyone please go through my code and let me know where am i going wrong.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let addPhotocell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellArray[indexPath.row]) as! AddPhotoTableViewCell
    if (indexPath.row == 1){
        addPhotocell.camera.image = UIImage(named: "icon-camera")
        addPhotocell.addphoto.tag = indexPath.row
        addPhotocell.addphoto.addTarget(self, action: "addPhoto", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2){

        addPhotocell.gallery.image = UIImage(named: "icon-gallery")
        addPhotocell.choosefromgallery.tag = indexPath.row
        addPhotocell.choosefromgallery.addTarget(self, action: "gallery", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    addPhotocell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    addPhotocell.selectionStyle = .None
    return addPhotocell;

}
```

Comment: Post a screenshot if possible

Comment: @iRealMe Sorry, I haven't got enough reputations to add an image...

Comment: Ok are you using dynamic tableview?

Comment: you can give link of image posted somewhere

Comment: what are the identifiers you have set in storyboard of both?

Comment: @iRealMe i am not using dynamic tableview i am using two prototype cells with different identifiers

Comment: it has been set in the following way   CellArray["TakePhoto", "gallery"].

Comment: Hi if you can let me know how to link an image over here i will do that... Meanwhile "TakePhoto" and "gallery" are two different identifiers set for each cell in the table view

Comment: Ok then it should be `0` instead of `1` and `1` instead of `2` in your code If I am not wrong

Comment: oh yeah... let me just try it and will let you know...

Comment: you can use dropbox or http://postimage.org/ or many others to post an image and then share the link

Comment: @iRealMe thank you :-) that was the silly mistake i was doing...

Comment: No problem, It happens!

Comment: I would like to add one more thing to this.. I am thinking to add 6 buttons in a popover how to call those buttons side by side...?

Comment: Not getting it. please post it as new question with necessary details(screenshots too)

Comment: k but its just a thought which i am about to implement..

Comment: @iRealMe As suggested by you i have posted it as a new question... please go through it

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add the buttons in the Interface Builder? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I have done it using storyboard TableViewController is my first view which consists of two prototype cells with two different buttons in each cell.